# Sum values in InfluxDB

Tags: influxdb

I’m tryingto sum values in InfluxDB but I’m struggling a bit.
So, I have a `_measurement` "plug" with a field "value".
I have different records within the same bucket with a different ID tag.

I can get the evolution of 1 plug with this query:

```
from(bucket: "test-bucket")
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "plug")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["id"] == "tag1")
|> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
|> yield(name: "mean")
```

What I would like is the exact same graph with the sum of all r["id"].
So, if there is 34 for tag ID "tag1", 11.2 for "tag2" and 0 for "tag3", I would like a graph with 45.2 for that given time.

I’ve tried to use «group()» method, but I get a strange value, more like an average than a sum.

I’ve also tried to use «sum» method, but then, I feel like Influx is summing all the values across the whole timeline.  That’s not what I want.

I just like to have a graph with with the sum of «value» field of all "tag" at  a given time.

Thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have a table per tag value. You can use [`pivot`](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/pivot/) function to merge into a single table, where all the different `_value` columns are now named after their corresponding tag value:

```
from(bucket: "test-bucket")
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "plug")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "value")
|> pivot(rowKey: ["_time"], columnKey: ["id"], valueColumn: "_value")
```

If you know the tag values in advance, the next step is easy:

```
|> map(fn: (r) => ({ _time: r._time, _value: r["tag1"] + r["tag2"] + r["tag3]}))
```

If you don't, it gets a bit more  complicated. What I would try next in this case is to write a function that combines [`experimental.unpivot()`](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/experimental/unpivot/) (note: available since InfluxDB 2.4) with `sum()`. The trick here is to call this method within `map()`, so it will operate on a single row (ie, single timestamp) at a time:

```
sumColumns = (r) => r
  |>experimental.unpivot()
  |>group
  |>sum()
  |>findRecord(fn: (key) => true, idx: 0)

from(bucket: "test-bucket")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "plug")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "value")
  |> pivot(rowKey: ["_time"], columnKey: ["id"], valueColumn: "_value")
  |> map(fn: sumColumns)
```

Note that I have not tested this. It is just to give you an idea.